# Margin-top -15px in IE makes icon to go bottom and -16px makes it go to top

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I want to put an icon right of the input to make it like combo. I have to use position relative because it must be complete code. And I will write a jQuery plugin and use it everywhere.

This is my code. Firefox and Chrome shows it properly but IE-9 has problem. If I do icon's `margin-top -15px` it goes a little bottom and if I do it -16px it goes to top of the input.

How can I solve this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTL>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:50%; position:relative; top:0; left:0; height:0; background-color:#ccc;">
    <input class="rounded" type="text" style="width:100%;">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/77" style="position:relative; z-index:2; float:right; margin-top:-16px; padding-right:5px;" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `top:-value;` 
i think it will useful to you

if you want to use `margin-top` only use this for ie9

`margin-top/*\**/:-16px\9;` 
and other browsers as u had given.

May be it will help you.

Comment: i dont use top. cause when i use it a space (icon's space) is viewing bottom of input. so i cant put a new element near bottom of input.

Comment: Which kind of witchery is that?!? `margin-top/*\**/:-16px\9;` worked for me! @Sam could you explain this?